# run shiny app within a running shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I've looked around, and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have created my app on R shiny and everything works great. I have 12 different csv files, each one containing information for a certain month. Problem is, each csv is 72000 KB. So right now, I only have it reading in 1 month. 
I was thinking about creating a server.R with something like

```
if(datasetInput() == "jan"){
  runApp("/file_for_jan")
}

if(datasetInput() == "feb"){
  runApp("/file_for_feb")
}
```

and so on. 
This way, it only loads in the specific month to look at currently.
Is this at all possible?
Or do you know of any smart, efficient way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to load all of your files into memory, like adding a '...please wait - loading data' progress bar.

Answer (score 4):

If you implement the code correctly, it will load each file once:

In server.R:

```
get.dataset = reactive(function(){
     month = input$month
     read.csv(csv fot this month)
 })

output$plot_whatever = renderPlot(
function(){
    dataset = get.dataset(input$momth)
    ...plot here
})
```

So you could load all your files once, OR load only demand (in this case, the first call will take a longer time).